# Opening a new UIVIewController by first deactivating UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I have three UIViewControllers: MainViewController, CurledViewController and SecondayViewController.

On MainViewController I have one UIButton in the MainViewController that displays the CurledViewController through:

```
curled = [[CurledViewController alloc] init];
[curled setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:curled animated:YES];
```

From the documentation I am told:

> A modal view presented using this transition is itself prevented from
>   presenting any additional modal views.

Which prevents me from opening the SecondaryViewController when the CurledViewController is displayed in this way. What I would like to do is, on the selection of a UIButton in CurledViewController, close the curl and open the SecondaryViewController (whether it's a call from CurledViewController or MainViewController doesn't matter). Upon closing SecondaryViewController, I would like CurledViewController to be re-opened.

In the function attached to the UIButton in CurledViewController I have attempted this through:

```
- (void)showSecondary:(UIButton *)sender {
   [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   SecondaryViewController *secondaryView = [[SecondaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Secondary" bundle:Nil];
   [self presentModalViewController:secondaryView animated:YES];
   ...
}
```

but am still told,

```
Application tried to present a nested modal view controller while curled
```

How do I go about opening a new UIViewController in this fashion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your code for presenting the SecondaryViewController is still executing from the CurledViewController. One alternative approach to try would be to create a CurledViewControllerDelegate protocol. Make MainViewController the delegate of CurledViewController and call your delegate method from showSecondary.

In CurledViewController, your method might look like:

```
- (void)showSecondary:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate dismissCurledViewController:self];
}
```

In MainViewController, your delegate method might look like:

```
- (void)dismissCurledViewController:(CurledViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    SecondaryViewController *secondaryView = [[SecondaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Secondary" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondaryView animated:YES];
    …
}
```

**Edit**

In order to keep the animations on both the dismissal and the presentation of the new modal view controller, you will need to introduce a delay that allows enough time for the first animation to complete. You can do this by invoking `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with an appropriate delay value. This is an error prone approach, however, as it assumes that the first animation will always have the same duration.

As [Andrew Pouliot suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160382/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-nonatomic/1160747#1160747) in another question, You could also try to override `viewDidAppear:` in your MainViewController, so that it looks for a flag to determine whether a SecondaryViewController should be presented. This would still use the delegate approach I mentioned above, but MainViewController would have the following differences:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(showSecondaryViewController) {
        SecondaryViewController *secondaryView = [[SecondaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Secondary" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:secondaryView animated:YES];
    }

    showSecondaryViewController = NO;
}

- (void)dismissCurledViewController:(CurledViewController *)controller {
    showSecondaryViewController = YES;  
    [self dismissModalViewController:YES];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but even with the call from the dismissCurledViewController function, the secondaryView is never displayed nor is an error reported. I am able to write to NSLog in this function and am even able to popup a UIAlertView, which displays while the curl transition is performing but it appears that any call to a UIViewController after the dismiss is not performed or least least not displayed. Any advice?

Comment: Try setting dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to NO to see if this is a timing issue with your animations.

Comment: Oddly, that worked. Is there a way to uncurl then perform the subsequent animation of secondaryView?

Comment: Actually, there's nothing odd about it. The YES for the dismissal animation in my original answer was a copy and paste error - it should have been NO. I didn't realize that you wanted to have both animations. I've updated my answer with an alternative approach that should let you keep both animations.